# Splitting a Pipe delimited text and passing it in a JS method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

Html:

```html
<div class="pageEdit" value="Create|8765678|FOOD=6578~-8765678?|9381">
 <a href="https://host:controller">Edit</a>
</div>
```

I want to get the value inside the `div` and pass that in a JavaScript method after splitting a pipe.

```js
$(".pageEdit").on('click',function(event){
            var data = $(".pageEdit").text().split("|");
            functionPageCreate(data(0),data(1),data(2),data(3));
    });
```

This is not working. I do not have much experience in JS/jQuery. Please, let me know how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use another attribute to store data.

```
<div class="pageEdit" data="Create|8765678|FOOD=6578~-8765678?|9381">
 <a href="https://host:controller">Edit</a>
</div>
```

Then retrieve it using

```
$(".pageEdit").on("click", function (event) {
  var data = $(this).attr("data").split("|");
  functionPageCreate(data(0), data(1), data(2), data(3));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
$(".pageEdit").on("click", function (event) {
  var data = $(".pageEdit").attr("value").split("|");
  functionPageCreate(data(0), data(1), data(2), data(3));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @kalpesh . It is able to get attribute value but is not doing splitting on that string.